# Debugging SmartTarget query URLs

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper

In my web application log files I see part of the Fredhopper query being logged:

```
2015-06-17 16:56:47,073 DEBUG Query - FutureTask - 103 - Constructing Fredhopper query
2015-06-17 16:56:47,158 INFO  Query - FutureTask - 103 - Executing query: fh_location=//catalog01/en_US/categories<{catalog01_tcm_0_19_1}&fh_user_date=20150617&st_region=Banner+List&st_active_period=20150617&st_publication=tcm%3A0-19-1&sc_auth_isauthenticated=false&sc_session_lifetime=0&sc_ua_isbot=false
```

It seems that the easiest way to debug and test the results of tweaking the queries is to directly query the Fredhopper Query Server by URL and see how the result set changes. I am not sure how to take this information from the log and build a full URL to query. Does anyone know the full Query URL syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Complementary to oic's answer, there are two ways to run a query:

The SmartTarget API runs the query against the **REST API** at `http://localhost:8180/fredhopper/query` (assuming the query server is on `http://localhost:8180`)

So in your case the REST URL is `http://localhost:8180/fredhopper/query?fh_location=//catalog01/en_US/categories<{catalog01_tcm_0_19_1}&fh_user_date=20150617&st_region=Banner+List&st_active_period=20150617&st_publication=tcm%3A0-19-1&sc_auth_isauthenticated=false&sc_session_lifetime=0&sc_ua_isbot=false`

The **Fredhopper Preview** URL is `http://localhost:8180/preview/` (assuming the query server is on `http://localhost:8180`)

So in your case the preview URL is `http://localhost:8180/preview/?fh_location=//catalog01/en_US/categories<{catalog01_tcm_0_19_1}&fh_user_date=20150617&st_region=Banner+List&st_active_period=20150617&st_publication=tcm%3A0-19-1&sc_auth_isauthenticated=false&sc_session_lifetime=0&sc_ua_isbot=false`

Make sure not to mix up the `/?` and `?` in those URLs. The REST API URL is `/fredhopper/query?fh_location=` and the preview URL is `/preview/?fh_location=`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Fredhopper preview page for this.  The preview URL is something like this:

http://localhost:8180/preview/?preview_seo=false&fh_location=//catalog01/en_US

Just replace the fh_location parameter with the one from the log.